# How to use xslt to step through an rss feed and only display the wanted information

Tags: xslt, rss

I want to look at an external rss feed and display it on my site but there's some excessive information in there which I don't want and I also want to add in my own content dependent on the content of the xml.

To try and make my explanation clearer a mock example would be an rss feed which includes the current day of the week and time. I would then want to pull that in, filter out the time to just have the day of the week, and replace that with an image relevant to the day of the week.

Edit: Okay, here is a possible example: [Yahoo - Today's weather rss](http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=44418&u=c)

This shows the current weather in London (along with a short forecast). How would I look at the text attribute of the yweather:condition node and display an image relevant to it, so if it says "Fog" as it currently does, I would display an image of fog, if it said sun, an image of a sun, and so on.

Comment: Please, provide a sample (complete and small) XML document and the exact wanted output result.

Comment: @_dudledok: You still haven't provided the exact wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/*/item/yweather:condition/@text
```

where you have registered in your PL (that hosts the XPath engine) the prefix `"yweather"`, associated to the namespace `"http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0"`.

**XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0"
 exclude-result-prefixes="yweather">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <img src="{/*/*/item/yweather:condition/@text}.jpg"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied against the XML document pointed to by the link in the question**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">
    <channel>
        <title>Yahoo! Weather - London, GB</title>
        <link>http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/London__GB/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/UKXX0085_c.html</link>
        <description>Yahoo! Weather for London, GB</description>
        <language>en-us</language>
        <lastBuildDate>Sun, 20 Nov 2011 2:50 pm GMT</lastBuildDate>
        <ttl>60</ttl>
        <yweather:location city="London" region=""   country="United Kingdom"/>
        <yweather:units temperature="C" distance="km" pressure="mb" speed="km/h"/>
        <yweather:wind chill="7"   direction="0"   speed="3.22" />
        <yweather:atmosphere humidity="100"  visibility="0.9"  pressure="1015.92"  rising="0" />
        <yweather:astronomy sunrise="7:26 am"   sunset="4:05 pm"/>
        <image>
            <title>Yahoo! Weather</title>
            <width>142</width>
            <height>18</height>
            <link>http://weather.yahoo.com</link>
            <url>http://l.yimg.com/a/i/brand/purplelogo//uh/us/news-wea.gif</url>
        </image>
        <item>
            <title>Conditions for London, GB at 2:50 pm GMT</title>
            <geo:lat>51.51</geo:lat>
            <geo:long>-0.13</geo:long>
            <link>http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/London__GB/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/UKXX0085_c.html</link>
            <pubDate>Sun, 20 Nov 2011 2:50 pm GMT</pubDate>
            <yweather:condition  text="Mostly Cloudy"  code="28"  temp="7"  date="Sun, 20 Nov 2011 2:50 pm GMT" />
            <description><![CDATA[
<img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/28.gif"/><br />
<b>Current Conditions:</b><br />
Mostly Cloudy, 7 C<BR />
<BR /><b>Forecast:</b><BR />
Sun - Cloudy. High: 9 Low: 8<br />
Mon - Mostly Cloudy. High: 12 Low: 10<br />
<br />
<a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/London__GB/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/UKXX0085_c.html">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a><BR/><BR/>
(provided by <a href="http://www.weather.com" >The Weather Channel</a>)<br/>
]]></description>
            <yweather:forecast day="Sun" date="20 Nov 2011" low="8" high="9" text="Cloudy" code="26" />
            <yweather:forecast day="Mon" date="21 Nov 2011" low="10" high="12" text="Mostly Cloudy" code="28" />
            <guid isPermaLink="false">UKXX0085_2011_11_21_7_00_GMT</guid>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
<!-- api9.weather.ac4.yahoo.com compressed/chunked Sun Nov 20 07:44:04 PST 2011 -->
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<img src="Mostly Cloudy.jpg"/>
```

**Update**: The OP has now provided in a comment the exact wanted output. Below is the transformation that produces this output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0"
 exclude-result-prefixes="yweather">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text
    disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML></xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="weather">
                  <img src="{/*/*/item/yweather:condition/@text}.jpg"/>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html> 
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the wanted result is produced:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="weather">
         <img src="Mostly Cloudy.jpg"/>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I create a fragment using the xslt you provided, how would I use the html output in an html page so that the image shows in a specified div.

Comment: @dudledok: Sorry, but I don't understand the question in your last comment. The core reason is that you haven't provided the exact wanted output and continue to ask vague questions.

Comment: The output from your code is perfect, but I want to output it into a div within an html page.
Wanted output:

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<div id="weather">
<img src="Mostly Cloudy.jpg"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @dudledok: I updated my answer with a transformation that produces exactly the output you provided in your comment.

Comment: I don't want to use xsl for everything because I have already created a mainly html and css solution which is why I was asking if it's possible to have an existing html page and retrieve the output from the xslt.

Comment: @dudledok: You have made a complete closed circle. Just use my first solution. You can instantiate the transformation from Javascript and insert the result using `document.write()` or any other appropriate technique (my JS is quite rusty), or you can even make an AJAX call to a server where the transformation is executed and the result returned. Anyway, this is no-longer XSLT-related at all.

Comment: I guess that was my question all along but I didn't know how to ask it because I didn't know what technique was needed. Thanks for the help and I guess I need to ask a new question.

Comment: @dudledok: You are welcome. Your new question most probably needs to be asked at `xsltprocessors` and at `jquery`.